# SPI communication with multiple slaves

Tags: microcontroller, avr, spi

I am working on a project that is using an ATtiny861A and this only has one SPI. If I want to hook up a radio and an external memory to the same SPI, will there be an issue sending data from the external memory to the radio? I know I can hook up the external memory and the radio to the same SPI but I am not sure if the radio will be able to send the data saved on the external memory.

Comment: Any particular radio?

Comment: It will be a CC2520 from Texas Instruments

Comment: I'm fairly sure you could run that as a master, making a multi-master system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your micro is the master and as such you can't get this type of bus to interact slave-to-slave. It's a case of reading the memory into the micro and then forwarding this to the radio i.e. the micro must buffer the data when sending it between slaves.

Comment: So they can communicate but the Micro-controller needs to hold the data before it is sent? Would this all be done in the coding?

Comment: Yes, it is done in the micro's coding

Comment: @Therusscher SPI being Master-Slave protocol, Everything must go through Master